# Android push notification showing big picture as white background

Tags: android, image, push-notification

In the app when we are sending push notification with Big picture sometime the big picture are shown and sometimes we are seeing white background in place big picture.

The issue is random not a device/OS[image] specific.

image on the server are of 500*277 which is in permitted width and height range.

Any efforts. are welcome

```
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                .setSummaryText(notificationData.getCleverTapMessage())
                                .bigPicture(bigPicture));
```

Comment: did u set ur notification style i.e. inbox style or big picture style??? I'd better if u post ur create notification code.